# Is boto3 1.9 is compatible with 1.5?

Tags: boto3

I use Airflow 1.9.0 with botocore 1.8.50 and boto3 1.5.18.

Now want to upgrade to boto3 1.9.86 and the botocore will also update to 1.12.86. I read the source code and didn't find any incompatible usage. But I am still nervous and want to confirm with boto experts.

Is the boto3 1.9 compatible with 1.5 ?

Thanks,

Yan

Comment: There was one potentially breaking change in 1.9.0, though it is unlikely that it will impact you. Essentially there was a fix made to the event system that cleared up ambiguities. See [upgrading notes](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/upgrading.html) for details including how to mitigate.

Comment: Thank you Jordon